# Using CSS ":contains:" with WebDriver in Python

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, contains

I'm migrating some Selenium WebDriver test cases from unittest to py.test and seeing an issue when I attempt to use the ***:contains()** command on a CSS Selector.  Here's an example of a line that fails:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.yui-skin-sam div[id=Navigation] ul[id=mainNav] li span:contains(Home)"))
    )
```

Any time I've attempt this command with a CSS Selector that does not contain ***:contains()**, it works fine.  Otherwise, I get either a TimeoutException or a InvalidElementStateException.  I've also tried using the following instead:

```
expected_conditions.element_located_to_be_selected
         "         .element_to_be_clickable
         "         .element_to_be_selected
         "         .presence_of_element_located
         "         .text_to_be_present_in_element
         "         .visibility_of_element_located
```

I'm fairly sure my issue has more to do with attempting to use ***:contains()**.  Attempting to use By.NAME, By.XPATH, or any other object name, it works fine.  Here's what I'm looking at with respect to the HTML Source on the page:

```
</div>
    <div id="HeaderBox">
        <div id="Content">
            <div id="Header">
                <div id="Left">
                    <img src="/images/header_logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="Right">
                            <div id="Text">
                            <div id='active_conf'>  running... </div><br>
                            Profile is unlocked. ( <a href="/Auth/Lock/">Lock</a>
                            | <a href="/Auth/Logout/">Logout</a> )<br>
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Navigation">

                    <ul id="mainNav">
                                <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/DataValues/"><span>DataValues</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Devices/"><span>Devices</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Does anyone know of a way I can get this to work?  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `contains()` with `ccsSelectors` but you can use the alternative `[attribute~=value]`, so in your case I would imagine `span[value~=Home]`

Comment: @Mark Rowlands : Thanks for the reply.  I gave what you said a try, but received a **TimeoutException** error back.  Via your suggestion, I tried the following:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(`
`expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.yui-skin-sam div[id=Navigation] ul[id=mainNav] li span[value~=Home]"))`
`)`

I also tried adding **~=** to all the other attributes, but received the same error.  Is it possible my css code is incorrect?

Comment: @Mark Rowlands : I added the HTML code in my description above for you to take a look at in case that's the issue.

Comment: Try xpath selector instead of css: `//ul[@id='mainNav']//span[contains(.,'Home')]`

Comment: Ah I see, its the text that you were trying to locate by. I try to avoid that where I can, instead I'd use a locator like `#mainNav>li:nth-child(1)>a>span` which means the first child element of with the id mainNav, which is an li, and then proceed down the DOM to the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this issue.  For starters, as @Mark Rowlands mentioned above, **contains()** can't be used.  I needed to make some changes to my CSS syntax as well so it would do a better job of pointing at the object I wanted to verify.  Finally, since I have an attribute, a located, and a value [where the value is the text located in **contains()**], I needed a method that allowed for all 3, which in this case was the **text_to_be_present_in_element** method.  So, to locate **Home**, I needed to do the following:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css=ul[id='mainNav'] > li:nth-of-type(1) > a > span"), "Home")
    )
```

I also could have used **a > span** instead of the long form listed and probably could substitute nth-of-type for **first-child**.  Now, if I want to locate one of the other values, **devices** for example, I needed to do the following:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[id='mainNav'] > li:nth-of-type(2) > a > span"), "DataValues")
    )
```

While I'm sure there are other solutions, these are the ones that worked for me.  Hope this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying I'm not very familiar with the Python bindings for Selenium (I use Java)... However, I had this same problem a while back.  I was able to solve this by injecting Sizzle.js onto the DOM to aid element location.  Sizzle brings with it the `:contains()` psuedo-class and support for other JQuery selectors as well.

I was able to find a small bit of info for Python [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/Ogqwxc6_4tQ), but I'm sure there's more thorough information out there.